# Azure Media Services Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, azure-media-services

I have a azure media services url like so: https://amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/3b970ae0-39d5-44bd-b3a3-3136143d6435/AzureMediaServicesPromo.ism/manifest

But when I try and play this on android I get the following error (also happens with dash url):

com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (MatroskaExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, TsExtractor, FlvExtractor, OggExtractor, PsExtractor, WavExtractor, AmrExtractor) could read the stream.

Does anyone know how to get smooth stream video to play in flutter? (The current state of video playback is really weak and I can't find any samples of smooth streaming but it says that it's exoplayer on android which should work)

Comment: have you solved this issue bro? i got same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those that might come here looking for a solution. It is a pretty trivial solution using the default video_player or even yoyo player. In front of the url, just add the file format type that you desire. For example for HLS just add ".m3u8" and for dash add ".mpd" and the video will work and still be adaptive.

So your full url should be something like this:

For HLS https://itvnnowoptimised-sano1.streaming.media.azure.net/3c0ecaef-002f-461f-854a-2397449d351f/thestoryofjoseph.ism/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl).m3u8

For dash https://itvnnowoptimised-sano1.streaming.media.azure.net/3c0ecaef-002f-461f-854a-2397449d351f/thestoryofjoseph.ism/manifest(format=mpd-time-cmaf).mpd

This was using azure Media Services.

Comment: They have also added a format hint enumeration now to the video player so you can force it without putting the extension on it.

Answer (score 0):

Presume you have seen this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/dynamic-packaging-overview) already. Can you please try with HLS?

Comment: I've tried the hls, dash and every other url listed on that page. I got the same error in every case.

Comment: Are you using the sample URL above, or are you generating one from content that you processed with our service? I'll ask my colleagues to test the above sample URL - else, we may need you to open a support ticket, so we can request network traces. Thanks

Comment: Can you share more details about how you set up your Flutter application or point to a repro that you have hosted in Github that we could look at? 

Which video player control are you using in the Flutter application? Looks like the error says ExoPlayer? Is it this one? https://github.com/danielR2001/flutter_exoplayer

Comment: I've tried every one on pub.dev.  Just using the video_player from the flutter team (which also uses exo on android) also fails.