# How can i use an encoded video streaming url manifest on flutter video_player

Tags: flutter, video-streaming, flutter-video-player

So I have a streaming link generated from encoding azure media services. Video plays on the test player there but now want to use the URL on flutter video player.

Below is an example of the link type to expect https://itvnnows-sano13.streaming.media.azure.net/be344295-3f54-4537-abd4-87435a3d51ea/ITVNNow.ism/manifest

On flutter video player, when I use URL with .mp4 extension it works but when using the above mentioned link nothing happens. Is there a possible workaround?

Comment: Hey, any solution for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58844066/azure-media-services-flutter/68275209#68275209. check this solution out @RazvanCristianLung .